# How to see full HTTPS URL in wireShark

Tags: python, networking, wireshark

I did enough research and failed to find a conclusive answer(version 1.12.7).

My local server is making a get call to `https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/12345.json` when I see this packet in `wireshark` I see the `destination URL` as `hacker-news.firebaseio.com`. My ask is simple

1) ***how can I see the entire URI including `/v0/item/12345.json` part.***

2) Why are somany dots in the following TCP stream and what does this TCP stream actually trying to say with jabbered English letters.

```
...........Z..d.2......j.q..n8..{."RE...wT...../.+.0.,...'.g.(.k.$...
.........j.i.h.9.8.7.6.2...*.&.......=.5.#...........@.?.>.3.2.1.0.1.-.).%
.....f.........localhost.........
.......3t......5...1..W:....".q.........m....r.>?t w..............#.................0...0..|.......%e.x.#s.0
..*.H..
.....0I1.0...U....US1.0...U.
.
Google Inc1%0#..U....Google Internet Authority G20..
151217200354Z.
161216000000Z0j1.0...U....US1.0...U...
California1.0...U...
Mountain View1.0...U.

..{.<...[L.......V..7.`?Yb.oF.z.....aC#..FtqyG0..p....-s...........d0.pe....3....5s.....T..y.F.I..w{.zX!...ou.db..j
<..+......y.]..`.{V ..q..z"P<T.,<.}..
..........._j.B.*F.\.0 gJa.E..........V).-z...].......t@..S!n......<......`...........>....:Q
```

And description

`244 19.329480000    sapy    hacker-news.firebaseio.com  TCP 435 47965→https [PSH, ACK] Seq=471 Ack=3948 Win=40576 Len=369 TSval=20106775 TSecr=4020547278   hacker-news.firebaseio.com  244`

Comment: Try using Charles Proxy, it is HTTP/HTTPS only and can install a proxy so you can see the unencrypted data as long as the certificate is not pinned. It is also much easier to use and has a 30-day free trial.

Comment: Another option is to use [Tamper Data](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/addon/tamper-data/) (or Tamper Chrome), it is a completely free software proxy inside the browser.  Although it has the downside that it cannot export PCAP files.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is that you are using https. That means that the only informations that you have directly are the peer address and the ports used. All exchanged data is encrypted, including the request itself that should be `GET /v0/item/12345.json`

TL/DR: you cannot. That is one of the goals of the https protocol: wireshark acts as a *man in the middle* and https protects your privacy.

Comment: when we make a `HTTPS` call from browser, it encrypts the data , But when I'm making the call from my node server , who is doing the task of hiding all data to an outgoing request which is hitting `wireshirk` first before hitting any DNS server ? Is there any other way I can see the entire URI ?

Comment: @sapy: at the moment the TCP packet is built, data is already encrypted. The only thing you can do is to log (of display *anywhere* the url you use to build the request before it is actually sent.

Comment: I changed the end point to a  different `HTTP` api `http://api.open-notify.org/` still can't see the full url

Comment: @sapy: When using a `http` protocol, wireshark does show the full URL. You should look in wireshark at the HTTP or TCP level.

Comment: this is incorrect, if you're using a browser you can use environment variables to force logging the SSL keys to a file and use those to decrypt the corresponding packets. for other applications, a transparent proxy would work instead

Comment: Hi @éclairevoyant , how to do that? I hope to capture a request triggered an installed app on my Windows machine. So I guess I need a transparent proxy, don't I? Could you please help to provide more info about your solution? Thanks!